# How to use class defined in a separate header within a namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, reference, undefined

I have a namespace in which I'd like to define a class. The class is rather complex so I'd rather define it in a separate header file, but even the simplest code gives me an "undefined reference" error.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A {
    #include "C.hpp"
}

int main()
{
    A::C foo;
    std::cout << foo.member << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

C.hpp

```
class C {
    public:
     C();
     int member;
}
```

C.cpp

```
C::C()
{
    this->member = 10;
}
```

When I run `g++ C.cpp main.cpp` I get "main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `A::C::C()'" error. I suppose that it's the C::C() definition of the constructor that is somehow wrong, but I'm uncertain how to fix it.

Comment: Well your definitions are of the wrong thing...

Comment: I'm going to assume you've done this because you're running into naming conflicts. At this point, I'm simply going to say, "I hope you've learned your lesson about neglecting namespaces when creating classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace A {
    #include "C.hpp"
}
```

This is a very odd thing to do.

This places everything declared in the header inside a namespace called `A`; specifically, it gives you a declaration of `A::C`, which is a different class to the `::C` you get when you include the header without a surrounding namespace.

You have provided a definition for `::C::C()`; but `main.cpp` requires a definition for `A::C::C()`, since that is the class it uses. That's not defined anywhere, hence the error.

Either put `C` properly into `namespace A` by moving the namespace to the header file (and fix `C.cpp` to use that namespace), or get rid of `namespace A`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define `C`'s constructor inside namespace `A` too:

```
namespace A
{
    C::C()
    {
        this->member = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: And hence, you have to decide what namespace the class belongs in up front. No `namespace A { #include "C.hpp" }` from one user and `namespace B { #include "C.hpp" }` from another. Unless the class and its members are defined entirely in the header, although I'm not recommending that either, since the two users would end up with two different classes that happen to have identical definitions. If a user dislikes the namespace chosen by the author of the class, they can write `namespace A { typedef HorridNamespace::C C; }` or `namespace A { using HorridNamespace::C; }`.

Comment: I see. So I either have to define the entire class in the header or include it outside the namespace? What is considered a better approach if the class won't be of much use outside the namespace?

Comment: @Steve: or simply `namespace A = HorridNamespace`.

Comment: Indeed, if you want the full contents of the namespace.

Comment: @user1134621: the better approach is that you should *never* write a `#include` inside a namespace. Where "never" means, "unless you're doing something really obscure that I haven't thought of and that justifies it". You want to be able to look at a file, and see what the fully-qualified names are of all the things in it. You can't do that if someone comes along later and sticks an extra namespace on the front by including from inside their namespace.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me, I now understand why it's not possible to do what I wanted without some ugly hacking.