# How to change boost namespace?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am using boost_1_49_0 version. I want to change the boost namespace used in my project.
I tried in following way -

Tried to add customized namespace in my project named XYZ by following way

```
namespace XYZ
{
.... Corresponding boost Headers
}
```

But failed to do so. There were some compilation error.

I want to use namespace of boost as following

```
XYZ::boost::thread
```

How I can accomplish that?

Comment: Probably you meant "namespace", not "namespacae" + what errors?

Comment: What is the reason to do this?

Comment: For avoiding conflicts

Comment: This ia a Bad Idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270435/includes-within-a-namespace-to-embed-prewritten-stuff-in-namespace What's the real problem?

Comment: What conflicts do you have?

Comment: We have two implementation version of boost. I want to use smart_ptr of one implementation version and thread of other one. This is for clients requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost's BCP tool, if you can get it to work, has the ability to rename the boost namespace to something else.

Comment: The instructions given in the boost bcp page are not working for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was successful in the task. I have used bcp tools which is present in boost library.
Firstly we need to build the bcp tools and then running the required bcp command it can be accomplished. If anyone face problem, please free to comment.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You can use an alias like this:

```
namespace XYZ = boost::thread;
```

and then you're good to go!

Comment: Actually u r right. But I am not sure is it going to work in my scenario or not. Suppose we have two implementation version of boost. I want to use smart_ptr of one implementation version and thread of other one because client requires this. Will this work in that case?

Comment: It depends, can you tell me what you've tried? Are you getting errors?

Comment: yes I am getting error. Previously I have included headers of boost thread in a customized namespace but got error for global scope...

Comment: Including headers in your own namespace is surely going to give you trouble though. I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this. It will end in [tears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270435/includes-within-a-namespace-to-embed-prewritten-stuff-in-namespace). 

If your clients care what you are using inside, they will find whatever solution you come out with very hard to code against.

If your clients do not care what you are using inside, e.g. you do not expose implementation details, then the requirements are foolhardy.

Comment: Then what is the probable resolution for this?

Comment: Talk to you clients and find out what they really need, or do not expose implementation details

Comment: There is a situation that someone is selling their precompiled static library, which is using a specific version of boostlib. If their clients are using a different version of boost,  which is really common, something terrible is going to happen.